# Set column value dynamically in a function

Tags: r, dataframe

I'am trying to set a column value dynamically be creating a function and defining which column i want to create and which column I want to evaluate via regex.
So far the function below works when I use the "ifelse" construct.
But I can't think of a way to leave out the "else" and just leave the column value if my regex does not match.

What I want to achieve is, that also after the second call to my function "set_column_value_by_regex" the quattro-models, that were matched in my first call, still have the value TRUE in column "four_wheel_drive".
Currently this is overwritten, as seen in the output.

```r
library(tidyverse)
#> Warning: package 'dplyr' was built under R version 3.5.2
#> Warning: package 'stringr' was built under R version 3.5.2

set_column_value_by_regex <- function(my_dataframe,target_column,test_column,regex,value_true,value_false="") {
  my_dataframe[[target_column]] <- ifelse(str_detect(my_dataframe[[test_column]],regex),yes = value_true, no = value_false)
  return(my_dataframe)
}

new_mpg <- set_column_value_by_regex(mpg,"four_wheel_drive","model","quattro",TRUE,FALSE)
new_mpg <- set_column_value_by_regex(new_mpg,"four_wheel_drive","model","4wd",TRUE,FALSE)

new_mpg %>%  
  select(model,four_wheel_drive) %>%  
  distinct(model,.keep_all = TRUE) %>% 
  head()
#> # A tibble: 6 x 2
#>   model              four_wheel_drive
#>   <chr>              <lgl>           
#> 1 a4                 FALSE           
#> 2 a4 quattro         FALSE           
#> 3 a6 quattro         FALSE           
#> 4 c1500 suburban 2wd FALSE           
#> 5 corvette           FALSE           
#> 6 k1500 tahoe 4wd    TRUE
```

Created on 2020-10-25 by the [reprex
package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a kind of an unusual function, and it seems you could do it in a simpler way.  But I'll just answer your question:

The problem is not your function, but what you are passing into the function.  In the second call you told the function to replace the value with FALSE if it didn't match, and so the function did what you said.  If you want it to keep the original value, pass the original value into the function.  Like so:

```
library(tidyverse)
#> Warning: package 'dplyr' was built under R version 3.5.2
#> Warning: package 'stringr' was built under R version 3.5.2

set_column_value_by_regex <- function(my_dataframe,target_column,test_column,regex,value_true,value_false="") {
  my_dataframe[[target_column]] <- ifelse(str_detect(my_dataframe[[test_column]],regex),yes = value_true, no = value_false)
  return(my_dataframe)
}

new_mpg <- set_column_value_by_regex(mpg,"four_wheel_drive","model","quattro",TRUE,FALSE)
new_mpg <- set_column_value_by_regex(new_mpg,"four_wheel_drive","model","4wd",TRUE,new_mpg$four_wheel_drive)

new_mpg %>%  
  select(model,four_wheel_drive) %>%  
  distinct(model,.keep_all = TRUE) %>% 
  head()

# # A tibble: 6 x 2
# model              four_wheel_drive
# <chr>              <lgl>           
# 1 a4                 FALSE           
# 2 a4 quattro         TRUE            
# 3 a6 quattro         TRUE            
# 4 c1500 suburban 2wd FALSE           
# 5 corvette           FALSE           
# 6 k1500 tahoe 4wd    TRUE
```

Comment: Thank you! 
This really solves my immediate problem!
I'm also sure that there some massively more elegant way to do this but I could not come  up with one as I had a hard time to evaluate the function-parameter as a column name when referencing with "$".

If someone has nicer way to do this I'm still interested and curious!

Comment: You're welcome.  Also welcome to stackoverflow (the best site on the internet!).  FYI, it's courteous when someone answers your question to accept the answer.  That gives them reputation, and gives you a badge (if it's your first one).  You will appreciate this when you gain more experience and can start answering other people's questions.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative way is to test whether the column already exists. If it does not, create it, if it does, logical `OR` its value with the new value. In the function below, I define default values to `value_true` and `value_false`.

```
set_column_value_by_regex2 <- function(my_dataframe, target_column, test_column, regex,
                                       value_true = TRUE, value_false = FALSE) {
  new_value <- ifelse(str_detect(my_dataframe[[test_column]], regex), yes = value_true, no = value_false)
  if(is.null(my_dataframe[[target_column]])){
    my_dataframe[[target_column]] <- new_value
  } else {
    my_dataframe[[target_column]] <- my_dataframe[[target_column]] | new_value
  }
  my_dataframe
}
```

Now test the function and compare its result with the result in [David J. Bosak's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64520785/8245406) answer.

```
new_mpg2 <- set_column_value_by_regex2(mpg,"four_wheel_drive","model","quattro")
new_mpg2 <- set_column_value_by_regex2(new_mpg2,"four_wheel_drive","model","4wd")

identical(
  new_mpg %>%
    select(model,four_wheel_drive) %>%
    distinct(model,.keep_all = TRUE),
  new_mpg2 %>%
    select(model,four_wheel_drive) %>%
    distinct(model,.keep_all = TRUE)
)
#[1] TRUE
```

Another way is to use a compound regex, `"quattro|4wd"`.

```
new_mpg2b <- set_column_value_by_regex2(mpg,"four_wheel_drive","model","quattro|4wd")

identical(
  new_mpg %>%
    select(model,four_wheel_drive) %>%
    distinct(model,.keep_all = TRUE),
  new_mpg2b %>%
    select(model,four_wheel_drive) %>%
    distinct(model,.keep_all = TRUE)
)
#[1] TRUE
```